# Errors from httperf

Tags: ssl, nginx

I use httperf for performance testing. I start many threads of httperf at the same time, but after running for a while I receive errors like this:

> "httperf: failed to connect to SSL server (err=-1, reason=5)"

How does this happen?

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0;i<30;i++)); do
./bin/httperf --server 192.168.2.1 --port=443 --uri / --ssl --ssl-no-reuse --timeout 10000 --rate 1000 --num-conns 50000000 &
sleep 1
done
```

The server is nginx-1.2.4, I don't know if it is the problem caused by the server.

Answer (score 2):

There is a theoretical maximum of sessions you can have established to a single web server from a single client. It is possible that you have reached this limit.

What identifies a TCP connection are a combination of

1. Source IP
2. Source Port
3. Destination IP
4. Destination Port

In this test, 1, 3 and 4 are static.
What remains is the source port, which have a maximum amount of 65535 ports. Not all of these are used for outgoing connections. Depending on your client operating system, this number is restricted to a shorter range (i.e. 65535-1024).

To see if you have exhausted the amount of possible sessions, do the following on the server:

```
netstat -na | grep source-ip | grep ":443" | wc -l
```

You will have to investigate the clients limits to amount of source ports to determine the maximum.

Comment: Shouldn't that netstat command be run on the client, not the server?

Answer (score 1):

If I get the error message right it displays the status of SSL_connect. In this case reason 5 would mean SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL (see ssl/ssl.h in OpenSSL) and one would get more details about the error by "look at error stack/return value/errno". Unfortunatly httperf does not provide more detailed information so one just can guess: It might be that it got ECONNRESET or EPIPE because nginx closed the connection. Maybe you find more information in the error log from nginx itself.

Comment: Thank you. But there is nothing about this in nginx server's error.log

Comment: @Wayne: this discussion does not belong to security.stackexchange.com (see http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might try stackoverflow.com but in any case the information you've provided so far are not enough to debug the problem.